# How to remove grey column near minimap in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone know what is the reason of displaying this grey column near minimap and how it could be removed?

The same behaviour is for all the themes. Also, update of extensions and their one by one disabling didn't give me any success.

[image]

Comment: Does this appear on all file types?

Comment: @carlfriedrich yeah, for all. finally, I've solved the issue with this [approach](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152816#issuecomment-1179493827)